# email is sent successfully using codeigniter from live linux multi domain server but not received

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am sending email using below configuration

```
            $config = array();
            $config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
            $config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
            $config['protocol']            = "smtp";
            $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
            $config['smtp_port']           = "25";
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
            $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('email');

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('contact@gmail.com');
            $this->email->to('yasin@gmail.com'); 
            $this->email->subject('Contact');

            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();
```

I am getting mail send successfully status, but email is not  receiving at other end.Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure its sending? Did you check the outbox? Spam folder?

Comment: If you are sure that is has sent (?), but not received at all, then surely it is an issue with the mail service provider, and not a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can have multiple reasons. If you are sending E-Mails like this it is very likely, that the receiving Mail Server is not accepting your mail, because you are missing some HEader Infos or you do not provide a certificate or in generel: You do not pass the spam filter.
Sending mails is not so easy. I recomment to you that you use an existing SMTP server which you log into and send it via this server.

You could try different domains and check whether any of them receives the mail(s) you send, maybe use 10 minute mails, or maybe you have different mails from diferent domains which could be tested whether they receive the mail or not. If you need more help, or an example, I can provide this for you as well.

**Edit:**
Some Mail Hoster do not put a mail without a certificate or something similar in a spam folder but do not accept it in the first place and the mail ist "lost" in the desert of the internet